# Exponent in the prime factorization of $3^{1024}-1$ belonging to the prime $p=2$

Tags: number-theory, prime-factorization

> Find the largest positive integer $n$ such that $3^{1024} - 1$ is divisible by $2^n$.

I am trying all powers of $2$, beginning from $2^0$ onwards; I believe the answer will be $n=\infty$, since $3^{1024} - 1$ is an even number and it can be divided by $2$, so it is divisible by all powers of $2$?

Comment: The exponent surely is finite because the number is finite.

Comment: The answer is $12$, but I only found that out with PARI/GP, not by hand.

Comment: I tried using logarithm, but I am still getting only one equation with two unknowns, which makes it difficult to solve.

Comment: @MathTise This does not work, you need modular arithmetic. Euler's theorem should be helpful. Another approach could be induction to show that $3^{(2^n)}-1$ is divisible by $2^{n+2}$ , but not by $2^{n+3}$

Comment: I also got the answer n=12, but I got by software and not by hand.

Comment: As a suggestion, start with a smaller exponent for practice.  $1024=2^{10}$ so, let's stick to powers of $2$.  Work the problem for $3^2-1$ and $3^4-1$ just to get a sense of what is being asked.

Comment: Thank You lulu, that did help to some extent, to understand and work out the solution;   however, unfortunately excel doesn't display numbers after 2^9, and neither does my calculator!   :-(

Comment: Well, aside from the answers in the duplicate questions, you might try induction.  Note that $3^{1024}-1=(3^{512}-1)\times (3^{512}+1)$ and so on.